# How many points are needed to intersect all elements in a sequence of measurable sets

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal B, \mu)$ is a probability space and $n\in\mathbb N$ is an arbitrary but fixed integer. Is it true that if $m\in\mathbb N$ and if $A_1,\ldots,A_m\in\mathcal B$ with $\mu(A_i)>1/n$, then there exist points $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in X$ such that for every $i\in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ one can find $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $x_j\in A_i$?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

The answer is negative provided $n>2$. Let the space $X$  consists of $n+2$ elements of equal measure, $\{A_i\}$ be the family of all two element subsets of $X$. Then $\mu(A_i)=2/(n+2)>1/n$ for each $i$. But for any $n$-element subset $X’$ of $X$ we have $X\setminus X’=A_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: He told me the elements $x_1,...,x_n$ are to be chosen after and depending on the sets $A_i$.

Comment: @Pp.. It is not essential. I showed that for *any* choice of $x_1,\dots, x_n$ there is $A_i$ which contains no $x_j$.

Comment: I see now. When $m$ gets large the $x_i$ can't be chosen.

Comment: @Pp.. In my example $m$ is completely determined by $n$, $m={n+2 \choose 2}.$